# Gitlab group members missing disappeared

Tags: docker-swarm, gitlab-ce

I am facing issues with members of some GitLab groups missing intermittently while installed using GitLab-ce docker images. This happened to me in a few Gitlab versions ( 16.4.5-ce.0 to 16.8.1-ce.0)
host OS is Amazon Linux
Installed using Docker-CE image
ldap authentication
impact on few groups

Checked error logs but coudnt find relvent error.Upgraded docker version from 16.4.5-ce.0 to 16.8.1-ce.0

Comment: Where is the logs ?

Comment: which log should I check for this kind of issue

Comment: We noticed most of the time this occurs at regular intervals like every day at 1.30 PM. but works somedays works smoothly